# How do you translate "listener" or "callback" / Comment traduire "listener" ou "callback" ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Salut,

Je suis en train de rédiger un rapport sur un projet informatique en français. Et je suis coincé dans la traduction du concept de "Listener" (Un objet qui attend que quelque chose arrive, et quand ça se produit il déclenche une method spécifique). Parfois c'est appelé "Callback"

Quelqu'un à une idée de comment je pourrais traduire ce mot ?

---

Hi everyone,

I'm working on an IT report that I've to write in french. And I'm stuck when I have to translate the concept of a "Listener" (An object that listen for something to happen, and when this happened it triggers specific methods), this is sometimes called "Callback".

Does anyone has a suggestion on how I can translate this ?

Comment: Microsoft [emploie](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language?langID=fr-ca) « écouteur » et « détecteur (d'évènements) ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il existe [quelques équivalents](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listener), mais ce n'est pas du tout dérangeant en informatique de garder des termes anglais.

Je pense que c'est mieux de les garder en anglais, que le rapport s'adresse à des informaticiens ou non.

En général la meilleure pratique est d'apporter une traduction ou une explication la première fois qu'on utilise le mot, puis d'utiliser le mot anglais dans le reste du rapport.

Par exemple :

> Notre application utilise des *listeners* (des objets qui attendent que quelque chose arrive, et quand cela se produit déclenchent une méthode spécifique). Ces listeners interviennent pour faire le lien entre la vue et le modèle. [...]

Comment: Je pensais effectivement faire ce que tu suggère, expliquer puis utiliser le mot en anglais. Mais je voulais d'abord chercher une traduction. Et j'avoue que le terme "écouteur" je trouve que ça sonne bizarre/pas adapté. Donc on va partir là-dessus